# How to use options when writing vimscript?

Tags: vim

It's very straightforward, but I can't find the answer online. I want to do something like this in a plugin file:

```
" MyChecker.vim
"
" Uncomment the following line to set the autochecker option
"set autochecker=1

if ISSET(autochecker)
   autocmd InsertChange * :call MyAutoCheckerFunction()
endif
```

How do I do the ISSET line? I'd rather not have to explicitly set autochecker=0, I'd like it to just check if autochecker exists.

Edit: When I try the following:

```
if &autochecker == 1
    ...
endif
```

I get this error message:

```
Error detected while processing MyChecker.vim:
line   32:
E113: Unknown option: autochecker
E15: Invalid expression: &autochecker == 1
```

Comment: Quick favor: can you create an answer with the solution you found (instead of editing it into the question)? It's more in keeping with our Q&A format. It makes it easier for people to locate and understand, and then people can vote on the question and the proposed solution separately.

Comment: Hi @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Please feel free to make those changes thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create custom options in vim. You need to create a global variable instead like:

```
let g:AutoChecker = 1

....

if g:AutoChecker == 1
   " ...
endif
```

Comment: Ah, ok. So if I want a user to change the "option", they have to put "let g:AutoChecker = 0" in their .vimrc?

Comment: If you're not explicitly setting the var, you're going to want to test  for it's existence with exists() as well.  See this: https://github.com/rson/vimscript-snippets/blob/master/idiomatic_plugin_mapping.vim#L13

Comment: OK, I see how to do it!  The example was very helpful as well. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

For general options, I use the following function: [lh#option#get()](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/vim-lib/trunk/autoload/lh/option.vim#56).
It first searches if `b:{varname}` exists to return its value, then `g:{varname}`. Otherwise the default value provided is returned if none of the variables exist.

For programming related options (i.e. options can can be overridden for specific filetypes), I use another function: [lh#dev#option#get()](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/dev/trunk/autoload/lh/dev/option.vim#48).

The *[C++ Options](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/cpp/trunk/doc/lh-cpp-readme.txt#512)* section of [lh-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) documentation indirectly explains the rationale behind these two functions.

Comment: This is really nice - I'm using some of your other scripts to do syntax aware text objects. Seems you've got a real treasure trove of extensions there.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved to the answer section from the question).

It seems the solution is this:

```
if exists('g:nameOfMyOption') && g:nameOfMyOption

     ...

endif
```